# Get a char from a CString

Tags: c++

I have created a function that has as input a char szMyChar; (using it in a switch statement).

Now I have a CString having just a char, lets say `CString strString = "A";`

An option to call the function could be:

```
if (strString == "A")
 CallMyFunc('A');
```

though it is clumsy. I tried atoi (returns 0) and casting though neither works.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Sun

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either I'm not quite understanding what you're asking, or it's as simple as:

```
CallMyFunc(strString[0]);
```

See [Accessing Individual Characters in a CString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72b2swax.aspx#_core_accessing_individual_characters_in_a_cstring) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
CallMyFunc(strString[0]);
```

The `[]` operator can be used to access individual characters just as with C strings.

Answer (score 4):

Can you just do

```
CallMyFunc(strString[0]);
```

?